# Cleanup the mis-tagging between C# and VB.NET

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

It has been happening since the beginning of Stack Overflow. It appears, that people will ask a question about .NET, specifically C# or VB.NET. To get more eyes on the question they will tag it with both language tags even though they only want the result to be one language.

The justifications for this seems to be that it is very easy to translate between the two. However, for someone completely unfamiliar with VB.NET (such as myself), even though I could translate it, I couldn't write it so answering my C# question with a VB.NET answer is annoying. As such I wouldn't tag my question with VB.NET.

Going with that justification if I can write code in Java and C#, I should be able to translate between the two and therefore could justify having both languages tagged. This is obviously nonsense because someone answering Java questions doesn't want to read a C# question and answer it. So why do we let this happen between these two tags?

I suggest we clean up the mis-tagging so only the relevant tags are on the question.

---

If the question is about .NET I suggest we remove the language tags altogether because it would be language agnostic between the .NET languages.

---

As of right now with the very broad and not very defined search of [`[c#][vb.net]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+vb.net?page=1&sort=newest&pagesize=50) there are 11700 questions tagged so its obviously not something I can do on my own, especially with a large amount being added each day.

Comment: It just doesn't matter, many [vb.net] programmers can readily adopt a [c#] answer.  And use it as-is, mixing the languages is very easy, or simply translate the syntax.  The other way around, well, not so common :)

Comment: @HansPassant And? I can code in Java and C# does that mean it would be appropriate to answer a Java question with C#? No. The same applies to C# and VB.Net , just because they are closely related doesn't mean it is appropriate to switch between the two as you please.

Comment: Comparing Java and C# does not make any sense.  The unbridled hatred shown by [c#] programmers to anything that smells like [vb.net] is unwarranted and unnecessary.  I suppose programmers have to hate something to live, plenty of stuff out there to choose from.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't hate VB.Net, not in the context of SO at least, I just think tagging with two language tags when you only want one just to get more attention to the question is wrong and abusing the system. People don't allow it for other languages but will for these two just because of how closely related they are and I think it's something that shouldn't happen.

Comment: @HansPassant Also don't focus on comparing C# and Java, I just picked another random language. Think of another common mis-tagging such as C and C++ yet for this one we don't allow it.

Comment: Well, good, be sure to use your [c#] expertise to answer some [vb.net] questions.  The distinction between the two languages can provide deep insight into the what makes the .NET framework tick.  And it has a very useful support assembly that is often quite useful in a C# program as well.  Learning coding techniques from each other is strong goal at SO.

Comment: @HansPassant True but in that case it is on the answerer to answer with back up evidence from the other language, not on the questioner because most of the time they won't know that, else why would they ask the question? And in that case only the actual language the questioner is using should still be tagged.

Comment: If I can accept an answer in languages A, B, or C, why the hell should you come by and decide which one is the only one that should be accepted?  Honestly, its none of your business what languages I am willing to accept an answer in.  Just leave it alone and let people decide for themselves.

Comment: @Will So if a question is tagged with Python, C, C#, JavaScript and asking for a method to sort a list you'd be fine with that?

Comment: If the OP wants an answer in any of those languages, yes.  And if someone doesn't want to answer because it has a tag they don't like on it, fine.  That's still on the OP.  You can express algorithms in many different languages, or even in a made up language.  Preventing people from doing this isn't going to improve anything.

Comment: @Will So having a question that has ways to sort a list in up to 5 languages, with multiple answers for each language for different approaches, that will generally happen, is a good thing for SO in your opinion?

Comment: I'm not going to play reductio ad absurdum with you today, sorry.  I disagree with your stated question for the given reasons. Good day to you, sir.

Comment: The real question is: what does a tag mean? Does it mark the language shown in the question or the preferred accepted language of the question? I think it is more annoying to tag a question with VB.NET and receive a C# answer. So I think the latter.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I think a tag organises a question into the categories it is about. A VB.Net question is not about C# so why tag it as such?

Comment: It seems to me that this is all based on definition and perception. What makes a question specific a VB.Net question? When the OP provides VB.Net code? Or is it a .net question, prefereably answered with VB.Net. Is it a bad thing to draw attention? Are tags are being misused for that purpose? What about a question that is tagged as .Net. Isn't that basically the same as VB.Net and C#? And what to do with a Java answer on a C# tagged question? Downvote it, delete it? Just because the tag didn't match?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I think half the reason I'm being disagreed with so much is that we have no consensus on what a tag actually is and what it should be used for.

Comment: I agree, that is why I think you should discuss that first, before you can even start to cleanup tags. But I think the outcome can only be a request for change. Since Tag cannot cover all needs. But I'm afraid that as long as functionality is not changed, the use of tags will not change.

Comment: FWIW I started out in the .NET framework with VB.NET but I ended up learning C# first because all of the important blogs, posts, books, and reference material are C# (i.e., there's no CLR via VB.NET, and there really doesn't need to be one); they're really not all that different; the difference is 5% at most in where it really counts, I can translate from VB.NET to C# in my head though it might be because I do it on a nearly daily basis and I come from a C background. Compare the C# tag activity to VB.NET, VB.NET is practically a ghost town compared to the wealth of information written in C#.

Comment: ... I feel like [C#] and [VB.NET] could be near synonyms in some cases but on the other hand there are programmers that love C# and hate VB.NET and vice versa; forbidding C# answers in VB.NET questions would probably leave a lot of questions without answers, but going in the opposite extreme (e.g., merging VB.NET and C# into [.NET] unless the question is about a difference between the two) would probably leave a lot of frustrated casual browsers that ended up with search results that take more effort to read and use.

Comment: I have noticed something related in the [tag:ruby] and [tag:ruby-on-rails] tags. There are plenty of questions that are tagged with both tags, or with just the [tag:ruby] tag that are purely about Rails APIs. Since I, personally, am not the least bit interested in Rails (but really like Ruby), that annoys me deeply. I have experimented with various combinations of ignored and favorite tags, but there is just no way to get only Ruby questions, and I also have given up on trying to explain the difference between a programming language and a library written in that programming language.

Comment: I am interested in [tag:c#], but neither [tag:vb.net] nor [tag:.net], and I would prefer questions that are about some .NET API to be tagged with *only* [tag:.net], and questions tagged with [tag:c#] to be *only* about the C♯ programming language.

Comment: *"If the question is about .NET I suggest we remove the language tags altogether because it would be language agnostic between the .NET languages."* So which language should answerers write the code in? The language tags are necessary to indicate this. Tagging them [.net] is not sufficient.

Comment: @CodyGray It depends on the question, if it is about something in the framework .NET should be fine, if it how to implement something with the language. That was more of a broad statement, but it should be more of a per case basis.

Answer (score 2):

> ### What are tags, and how should I use them?
>
> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. **Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer** by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.

Right there is the purpose of tags, don't over think it. The main users of the tags aren't askers, nor visitors, but answerers, since they leverage the system to output answers, and whose time is valuable. I would be very annoyed if stuff that I'm not able to answer appear at every step, so disambiguation is always welcomed.

Comment: BTW, if someone is interested in C# or VB.net, they may just follow the tag if they are interested. No need to shove it to them just because.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: It depends. Clean up, but only where necessary.

The key point where I have to disagree is that comparing VB.NET and C# is completely different from comparing Java and C#. Converting [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) code from VB.NET to C# or vice versa can be done by an online converter. But you surely can't easily translate from Java Swing to Windows Forms. Or WPF. The same goes for clipboard handling, reflection, etc. The questions that are not specific for VB.NET or C# are not worth the effort and reduce helpful visibility.

Questions with both tags about language features, like operators, keywords, etc. should be cleaned up. I hope though that this should be a small subset of the questions tagged with both C# and VB.NET.

Comment: But when is it necessary? And why narrow to a specific language? In the past PHP code has helped me to accomplish building something with C#. It is not always about the language, but the suggestion that helps. Not all code has to be converted.

Comment: Note that Java/C# was an example. Another example, that actually happens, is tagging a question with C and C++, I'm sure most code can be translated between the two with some adjustments. However, for this if a question is tagged with both it is retagged accordingly.

Comment: If you can paste (or easily convert and paste) C++ code into a C project and vice versa I don't understand why it is retagged

Comment: Would you also justify not allowing to speak british english in America because you would then also have to allow spanish (what you obviously wouldn't have to because it is a completely different language)

Comment: @Breeze C# and VB.NET are *different languages*, not different dialects of the same language.

Comment: @Servy Technically you're right but since they both translate to the same IL their features, limitations, syntax, and overall algorithm design strategy are incredibly similar or identical.

Comment: @Breeze Even if you *could* compile all C code as C++ (you can't, you can compile *most* of C90 as C++98, but that's about it), good C++ code looks quite different from good C code. Just because something is a valid C answer that happens to work as C++ does not mean it's a useful C++ answer. So please, for all future readers, tag C as C and C++ as C++. There is no C/C++.

Comment: @jrh: By your argument, PASCAL and Haskell are the same, since they both can be translated to the same language. Hey, they even (sort-of) rhyme! *Every* language can be translated to *every other* language provided the target language is (computationally) powerful enough. In particular, CIL is Turing-complete, which means that *every* language can be translated to CIL. Which, by your argument, means that all languages are (almost) the same?

Comment: @JörgWMittag That's not what I'm saying though. I would never make the same claim about C++ and C#, C and assembly, or even C++ and C or Java and C#. Though just wondering, do you have a hard time reading VB.NET as a C# programmer? (Though I like your idea of tagging questions about the .NET API with [.NET], I think that would probably help out most of the questions)

Comment: @jrh: Actually, yes, I would probably find it easier to read examples in Scala, Ruby, Python, or F♯ (for example) than in VB.NET. It's all a matter of familiarity.

Comment: @JörgWMittag ah, I see, interesting. For me the differences between C# and VB.NET don't really help or hurt my productivity much (personally as far as readability goes I prefer C or C++ over the .NET languages and I'd rate C# and VB.NET about the same, even though I use .NET on a daily basis).